# Observable Timer for screen timeout android

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm working on a use-case where I have to implement a sort of screen timeout after the completion of which application navigates to the main screen. I want it to implemente it using `Observable` and use `Observable.timer()` or `Observable.interval()` for the timing.  (Either is suitable for my use-case.).  Every time the user interacts with the activity I have to reset or refresh my timer `Observable`.

This is where I am stuck. I don't know how to refresh or reset an `Observable`. A simple way would be to dispose the previous one and create a new one each time in `onUserInteraction()`, but I do not think that a good approach.  What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to this problem is not as simple as one might think. I have tried implement different approach. Instead of "clear or reset" observable, I'm using `BehaviorSubject` what is both `Observer` and `Observable`.

```
public class RxTimerNavigation {
    private final long TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 4;
    private final BehaviorSubject<UserInteraction> userInteractionsSubject = BehaviorSubject.create(UserInteraction.IGNORED); // (1)

    public void onInteraction() {
        userInteractionsSubject.onNext(UserInteraction.IGNORED); // (2)
    }

    public Observable<UserInteraction> getTimerExpiration() {
        return userInteractionsSubject
                .timeout(TIMEOUT_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // (3)
                .filter(__ -> false) // (4)
                .onErrorReturn(__ -> UserInteraction.FINISHED) // (5)
                .first() // (6)
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .asObservable();
    }

    static class UserInteraction {
        static final UserInteraction IGNORED = new UserInteraction();
        static final UserInteraction FINISHED = new UserInteraction();
    }
}
```

Let's explain marked parts:

1. `BehaviorSubject` receives and emits `UserInteraction` objects
2. Everytime user interacts with UI, you should call method `onInteraction()` and new item is "added" to Subject.
3. Sets Timeout. It throws `TimeoutException`, when there is no emitted item for specified amount of time (`TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`). Timer is started when you call `subscribe()` on `Observable` provided by `getTimerExpiration()` method.
4. We ignore all the emitted items, because we are waiting for the exception
5. We are "transforming" exception to `UserInteraction.FINISHED` object
6. We want emit only one value, because we are finishing

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'll definitely try this and will let you know if this works for me. Thanks anyway, for such a detailed, succinct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a perfectly valid approach. Dispose / unsubscribe the existing, obsolete timer and start a new observable with the now-correct values. If you have too many user interactions that may cause undue performance

The other way to do this is to have something like a volatile `expected-blank` value that is updated every time the user interacts with the application. You start a timer that will trigger on that `expected-blank` moment, and which checks whether that value is in the future. If it is, it starts a new instance of the timer and completes. If it is in the present/past, it blanks the screen and completes.